# Skyscanner API does not return data for flight search

Tags: skyscanner

I am playing around with the Skyscanner API from their [webpage](https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#flights-browse-prices) in Postman (opens in a new tab, or in the Postman desktop app) and testing the endpoint for browsing flights. This is what the API says in their page:

[image]

And this is what I am trying - browsing for flights from Stockholm Arlanda Airport (ARN-sky) to Heathrow (LHR-sky), on the date 22nd July (around 4 days from now) for first leg, and 25th for return, but as you can see, I am not getting any result. The URL I am trying is [this](http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/FR/eur/en-US/us/ARN-sky/LHR-sky/2021-07-22/2021-07-25?apikey=%3Capi-key%3E).

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, mind that you present an image regarding an endpoint to *Browse Quotes*, but you are trying to consume an endpoint to *Browse Routes*.

Assuming that you actually want to *browse routes*, I believe the problem may be this:

- The endpoint is of the form:

```
GET /browseroutes/v1.0/{country}/{currency}/{locale}/{originPlace}/{destinationPlace}/{outboundPartialDate}/{inboundPartialDate}
```

- You are writing a URL like:

```
.../browseroutes/v1.0/FR/eur/en-US/us/ARN-sky/LHR-sky/2021-07-22/2021-07-25?apikey=<api-key>
```

So it seems that you are actually specifying:

- `originPlace` = `us`
- `destinationPlace` = `ARN-sky`

But I think you wanted to define:

- `originPlace` = `ARN-sky`
- `destinationPlace` = `LHR-sky`

To solve this, you may remove the `/us` member, thus writing: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/FR/eur/en-US/ARN-sky/LHR-sky/2021-07-22/2021-07-25?apikey=api-key

- (Please, replace the `api-key` value by an actual API key)
- This URL already returns a valid `200 OK` result :)

Comment: Yup. That seemed to be the issue. Thank you so much!